# Rails 4: Any way to fix/use regular html href links w/o 'link_to'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, href

So my question is that I have a link to 'pages/home' and I click on it, ill go to my home page.

But then I'll try to click again, but the link changes to 'pages/pages/home' and then I'll get a routing error. Is there anyway to fix this using regular old anchor tags? or do i need to use link_to?

edit:
This is how i insert my link into the page.

```
<a href="pages/home">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to rails, the problem is you use a relative url :

```
<a href="pages/home">Home</a>
```

This will lead to `<any_path_you're_in>/pages/home`.

For it to be absolute, you have to use (note the leading slash):

```
<a href="/pages/home">Home</a>
```

By the way, it's quite a bad practice to use hardcoded url to your own rails app. You can avoid using `#link_to` while still taking advantage of rails' routing :

```
<a href="<%= home_path %>">Home</a>
```

Provided you have a "home" route, of course :

```
get '/pages/home' => 'pages#home', as: 'home'
```

This will save you a lot of pain when you decide to restructure your app.